# Как добавить значения в словарь по ключу, если значение - это список, который может и не существовать

Tags: python, list, словари, dict

Можно с проверкой есть ли уже такой ключ в словаре и если нету, то добавить пару ключ-значение. Иначе использовать метод append(). Но можно ли добавить новое значение в список по ключу, если не известно есть ли уже в словаре пара с таким ключом, при этом не использовать условие? Допустим через update(key: value), но тогда получается не список, а строка. А если в value взять в скобку [value], то значение будет не добавляться в список, а обновляться в списке (происходит замена старого значения на новое).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше всего использовать `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['key'].append('val')
```

Если вы не можете использовать `defaultdict`:
Вариант 1.

```
d = dict()
d['key'] = d.get('key', []) + ['val']
```

Вариант 2

```
d = dict()
try:
    d['key'].append('val')
except KeyError:
    d['key'] = ['val']
```